# htaccess Redirect Single Page to Different Domain without Parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have a site with the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\index.html/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?uri=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

There are two pages that I need to redirect to a different domain. Currently I have them setup as 302 redirects with the following line:

```
Redirect 302 /some-url-slug https://example.com/some-new-url-slug
```

This does work to redirect to the new domain but the issue is it's adding the uri parameter to the  redirected url so I get something like:

```
https://example.com/some-new-url-slug?uri=some-url-slug
```

I thought adding it above the rewrite rule would solve it, but it does not. How can I omit that rule but only for 2 specific pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought adding it above the rewrite rule would solve it

The `Redirect` directive belongs to mod_alias, the other directives are mod_rewrite. It doesn't matter where you place the `Redirect` directive, it will always be processed *after* mod_rewrite. And the `Redirect` directive will preserve the query string.

You need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` instead, at the top of the file, for these two specific redirects. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^some-url-slug$ https://example.com/some-new-url-slug [QSD,R=302,L]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive does not start with a slash. The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag ensures that any query string that might be present on the initial request is discarded (otherwise it is passed through by default).

**UPDATE:**

> I just realized that adding a trailing / to the url loads the original page. Do I need to create a seperate redirect rule for links that have the trailing slash?

You can include this in the same rule and make the trailing slash optional with the addition of `/?` at the end of the pattern. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^some-url-slug/?$ https://example.com/some-new-url-slug [QSD,R=302,L]
```

This now matches both `some-url-slug` *or* `some-url-slug/` and redirects to the URL as before.

Comment: I just realized that adding a trailing / to the url loads the original page. Do I need to create a seperate redirect rule for links that have the trailing slash?

Comment: @user10012 You can include an optional trailing slash in the same rule. I've updated my answer.